# Write $Z = 3 + 6i$ in the form $\rho e ^{i \theta}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I write $Z = 3 + 6i$ in the form $\rho e ^{i \theta}$?

Note: $$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$3 = ρ\cos(t), 6 = ρ\sin(t)$$
Dividing one by the other gives:
$$\tan(t) = 2 \rightarrow t = \arctan(2)$$
Square them both and add them together (equivalent to finding the magnitude)
$$ρ(\sin^2(t) + cos^2(t)) = ρ = \sqrt{3^2 + 6^2} = 3\sqrt{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\rho=\sqrt{3^2+6^2}=\sqrt{45}=3\sqrt 5$ and $\theta=\arctan\frac{6}{3}=\arctan2$. So we have $Z=3\sqrt 5e^{i\arctan(2)+2k\pi i}$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.